# SDL_SetVideoMode tries to free a pointer that hasn't been malloc'd (?)

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, sdl

I wrote a JNI library, and it's defined as such in Java:

```
public class SDLMain 
{
    static {System.loadLibrary("SDLBitsX");}

    public static native void init();
}
```

Defined in C as:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_gd_verfolgungsja_sdlbitsx_SDLMain_init(JNIEnv * env, jclass this)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(512, 512, 8, 0);
    SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

The Java code spits out:

```
2013-03-29 22:34:01.796 java[10851:1303] _NSSetWindowTag, error clearing window tags (1000)
2013-03-29 22:34:01.797 java[10851:1303] _NSSetWindowTag, error setting window tags (1000)
2013-03-29 22:34:01.799 java[10851:1303] error [1000] getting window resolution
2013-03-29 22:34:01.799 java[10851:1303] Error [1000] setting resolution to 1
2013-03-29 22:34:01.800 java[10851:1303] error [1000] setting colorSpace to Color LCD colorspace
java(10851,0x107b58000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff8c03af01: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The function works fine if I comment out the

```
SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(512, 512, 8, 0);
SDL_FreeSurface(screen);
```

I'm on a Mac. Why does it do this?

Comment: Did you check if `SDL_SetVideoMode` succeeds in creating a SDL_Surface, freeing a random pointer results in UB.

Comment: @armin Even if you don't free the surface, it'll still just bork. The problem is within SDL_SetVideoMode, I think. Also, I'm using the SDL.framework provided by libsdl.org.

Comment: Does it include <stdlib.h> and <stdio.h>?

Comment: @armin It does include <stdio.h>. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used SDL on a Mac but off the bat your call to `SDL_FreeSurface(screen)` is invalid.. *(IIRC you don't normally free the default working surface by yourself)* the default drawing surface is automatically freed by `SDL_Quit()` so in your case `SQL_Quit()` is trying to free something that does not exist.

Comment: Even if you comment that line out it still flops.

Comment: that code alone is weird, you just create a surface and then try to delete it twice.. *in a function* do you get the same error when you comment out the SDL_FreeSurface(screen) ?

Comment: Yes, read my above comment. (Also, the reason this code does almost nothing is that I'm just testing out stuff to see if it works)

Comment: hmm.. try adding a flag such as SDL_SWSURFACE http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html